# Read objects from a file and output them into a single line into another file

Tags: java, arrays, object, serialization, iostream

Currently I have an object array that I wrote into a .ser file. Now what I want to do is make individuals appear only once into another file with all their numbers added up. So far I wrote each line with their updated number from the function but not sure how to only make them only appear once with all the numbers added up.

This is my code:

public class IOStream {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Person[] people = new Person[14];
    people[0] = new Professor("Professor", "Issac", "Newton", "Physcis", 6);
    people[1] = new TA("TA", "Marie", "Curie", "Physics", 6);
    people[2] = new Professor("Professor", "Issac", "Newton", "Calculus", 4);
    people[3] = new Student("Student", "Amy", "Adams", "Calculus", 4);
    people[4] = new Student("Student", "Will", "Smith", "Calculus", 4);
    people[5] = new Student("Student", "Brad", "Pitt", "Physics", 6);
    people[6] = new Student("Student", "Will", "Smith", "Physics", 6);
    people[7] = new Professor("Professor", "Dimitri", "Mendeleev", "Chemistry", 6);
    people[8] = new TA("TA", "Carl", "Gauss", "Calculus", 4);
    people[9] = new Student("Student", "Amy", "Adams", "Economics", 3);
    people[10] = new Professor("Professor", "Adam", "Smith", "Economics", 3);
    people[11] = new TA("TA", "Marie", "Curie", "Chemistry", 6);
    people[12] = new Student("Student", "Brad", "Pitt", "Chemistry", 6);
    people[13] = new Student("Student", "Will", "Smith", "Chemistry", 6);

    //WRITING
    try ( ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object.ser"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            out.writeObject(people[i]);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //READING INPUT
    try ( ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("object.ser"))) {
        ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.ser"));
        Person lol;
        Person [] list;
        int i;
        while ((lol = (Person) in.readObject()) != null) {
            
           writer.writeObject(lol.title + " " + lol.fName + " " + lol.lName + " " + lol.getParticipatingHours(lol.courseHours));
            
        }
    } catch (EOFException i) {
        //System.out.println("lol");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
    }       
    try {
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("output.ser"));
        Object line;
        while ((line = reader.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (EOFException i) {
        //System.out.println("lol");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   

}
```

}

this is my output read from the output file:
run:
Professor Issac Newton 4
TA Marie Curie 2
Professor Issac Newton 3
Student Amy Adams 4
Student Will Smith 4
Student Brad Pitt 6
Student Will Smith 6
Professor Dimitri Mendeleev 4
TA Carl Gauss 1
Student Amy Adams 3
Professor Adam Smith 2
TA Marie Curie 2
Student Brad Pitt 6
Student Will Smith 6

Comment: What part of doing this are you stuck on?

Comment: By the way, never use an empty catch block -- if an error happens you will not know.

Comment: I'm basically stuck on where all instances of issac newton needs to be one instance but all the numbers added up so the result should be one line (Professor Issac Newton 7)

Comment: Look at the Map interface.